# Android App and REST API

Tags: android, rest, httpclient

I searched for good REST / HTTP Clients for Android-Development, but I did not found something   that meets my needs.

Now I have a question. Is there a good way to reuse HTTP client-objects in an android project?

It would be good if there is a central place (maybe static class?) to access an httpclient to do request (async)...

How can I  do this in an android project?

Same thing for my credentials. (I use basic auth and do not want to pass the credentials from activity to activity)

Comment: are you REST services serving JSON content?

Comment: yes, I use JSON content. btw: sorry I did not meant the R class (I meant the ressources, but they are xml files... so... :P)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you RoboSpice:

> RoboSpice is a modular android library that makes writing asynchronous
>   network requests easy.

It does have a cache manager, and works as service, which is, to me, better than common AsyncTasks.

https://github.com/octo-online/robospice

Also, you should **not** touch the R class, it is automatically built from your ressources.

Comment: <Super extra bold with a million exclamations> "you should not touch the R class"</>

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out

https://github.com/posco2k8/rest_loader_tutorial

---

I would also suggest a minor improvement change `RESTLoader.RESTResponse data` so as `data` be the final data in that case `List<String>` so as the parsing moved to the acync loader and avoid latency on UI thread. Adding the code pointing out the suggestions for change.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<RESTLoader.RESTResponse> loader, RESTLoader.RESTResponse data) {
    int    code = data.getCode();
    String json = data.getData(); // <-- (change) this should be the final data

    // Check to see if we got an HTTP 200 code and have some data.
    if (code == 200 && !json.equals("")) {

        // For really complicated JSON decoding I usually do my heavy lifting
        // Gson and proper model classes, but for now let's keep it simple
        // and use a utility method that relies on some of the built in
        // JSON utilities on Android.
        List<String> tweets = getTweetsFromJson(json); // <-- (change) that parse move to loader

        // Load our list adapter with our Tweets.
        mAdapter.clear();
        for (String tweet : tweets) {
            mAdapter.add(tweet);
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load Twitter data. Check your internet settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said RoboSpice is a very good choice. If you want to simply keep your local resource syncronized with remote data you can use [RestDroid](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid) which is a "resource oriented" library to handle asynchronous REST request.